# custom loss function that penalise a specific feature in keras

Tags: keras, loss-function

I am using keras and I have a neural network model with 10 features for a regression problem.

I would like to penalise one of the features during the training, so that the model does not predominantly use that feature for its predictions. To achieve that I thought about modifying the loss function in the same fashion as L1/L2 regularizers, but with a penalisation term which only depends on the weights of the first hidden layer which are related to the feature I want to penalise.

I tried to do this using keras, implementing a custom loss function, but I am not really able to access the weights of the model inside this loss function. How can I do it?

I tried to define a custom loss function:

```
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
def custom_loss_with_penalty(model, feature_index, penalty_weight):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            # Calculate the MSE loss
            mse_loss = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred))
            
            # Get the model's weights
            # Extract the weights associated with the specific feature to penalize
            # Only the Wij which are in the even indices of the list model.trainable_weights
            feature_weights = model.layers[0].trainable_weights[0][feature_index] 
            #print(model.layers[0].trainable_weights[0][feature_index])

            # Calculate the L2 penalty term on the feature weights
            penalty_term = K.sum(K.square(feature_weights))

            # Combine the MSE loss and the penalty term
            total_loss = mse_loss + penalty_weight * penalty_term
            
            return total_loss
        
    return loss
```

And call it when I compile the model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(30, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (X_train_scal.shape[1:])),
    keras.layers.Dense(25, activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

feature_index = -1 
penalty_weight = 0.01
model.compile(loss = custom_loss_with_penalty(model, feature_index, penalty_weight),
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
              metrics = ['mse'])
```

The point is that if I uncomment the line `print(model.layers[0].trainable_weights[0][feature_index])` in the custom loss function, I get the following output during the first epoch:

```
Tensor("loss/strided_slice:0", shape=(30,), dtype=float32)
```

But if I run the same line outside of the custom loss function I get this:

```
tf.Tensor(
[ 0.6760862   0.4757735   0.67131263  0.41614223  0.7793487  -0.01518224
  0.6795032   0.13732705 -0.083634    0.46164796 -0.04648072  0.17970403
  0.60452724  0.04628336  0.63420105 -0.14613572  0.78324324  0.28219488
  0.7852035   0.345836    0.5653611   0.6162754   0.5593022   0.70427567
  0.13057987  0.6127586   0.43478504  0.21638864  0.14894344 -0.1527218 ], shape=(30,), dtype=float32)
```

So it's like as if inside the custom loss function I am not able to access the actual trainable weights values of the model. I don't know if this makes sense, but in any case it seems that my penalisation term is doing nothing, regardless the penalty_weight I assign to it, which makes me think that it's not taking the weights at all.

**UPDATE**: I actually found a workaround to do what I want. I scale with a factor the feature I want to penalise and then I use L2 regularization, which will penalise more the feature I scaled because it will have bigger weights than the others. In any case I am still curious to know if it's possible to modify manually the loss function using the trainable weights.